# Android keyboard problems on textedit

Tags: android

I have problems with keyboard on numeric textedit

on textedit click keyboads appears ok , numeric keyboard, but after pressing ready keyboard dont dissapear , she is switched to alphabetical,

this problem apeared after I added a list view bellow in my layout, on pressing on alphabetical keyboard I navigate into listview

can anyone help me ?

Comment: please provide code and try to describe your problem more clearly

Comment: After I type keyboard dont disapear , but appear alphabeticaly keyboard,,,,,,,,,,,

this problem appeared after i added list view bellow in my layout

Comment: On the keyboard is there a done or a next button?

Comment: first time is done , but after i press done, appear another alphabetical keyboard
,,,,,,,and on the next editing is next button

Comment: ok i need to see your xml

Comment: also are you overriding the keyboard in any way?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SZwEizUt

Comment: Take a look here: http://savagelook.com/blog/android/android-quick-tip-edittext-with-done-button-that-closes-the-keyboard

Comment: the same problem, softkeyboard dont appears but next button appears and listview is not refresher but new items are appended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you add `android:focusable="false"` to the ListView XML file, it should fix it.

Comment: This will probably work, but if you change the layout, you'll have to remember to keep putting this

Comment: this doesnt work , soft keyboard also appears